# Server side code to handle HttpURLConnection in Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, file-upload, httpurlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection class to upload text file to my Apache server. For server side code I used php to handle the POST request. I was wondering , how the same thing can be done other then PHP, or the PHP is the best way to handle file uploading on server side?..Also I cannot find any jsp or java code on server side to handle http post request..any code snippet that does same thing other then PHP would be really helpful..Cause I think java or jsp would be easier to code ..Thanks

Android code to upload file:

```
  public void upLoad()
{


     String exsistingFileName = path+"//"+"test.txt";

     String lineEnd = "\r\n";
     String twoHyphens = "--";
     String boundary = "*****";
     try {
         // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

         Log.e(Tag, "Inside second Method");

         FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                 exsistingFileName));

         // open a URL connection to the Servlet

         URL url = new URL(urlString);

         // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

         // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);

         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);

         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);

         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                 "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);


         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=uploadedfile;filename="
                         + exsistingFileName + "" + lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

         Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

         // create a buffer of maximum size

         int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         int maxBufferSize = 1000;
         // int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
         byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];

         // read file and write it into form...

         int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

         while (bytesRead > 0) {
             dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
             bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
         }

         // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

         dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

         // close streams
         Log.e(Tag, "File is written");
         fileInputStream.close();
         dos.flush();
         dos.close();

     } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
         Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
     }

     catch (IOException ioe) {
         Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
     }

     try {
         BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn
                 .getInputStream()));
         String line;
         while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             Log.e("Dialoge Box", "Message: " + line);
         }
         rd.close();

     } catch (IOException ioex) {
         Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
     }
}
```

Php code on server side :

```
 <?php
 $target_path  = "./upload/";
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
" has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }
?>
```

Comment: you can search on google many google tutorials available for uploading file on server using PHP web service

Comment: Does the code above actually work for you? I am using something very similar and I am not seeing anything in the $_FILES array on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no correct answer for this question, PHP can be good as JSP or even ASP. Depends on your platform preference or if you are planning on having a tomcat vs apache server or even a microsoft iis server. Personally I think PHP/Apache is a good choice.

Comment: Thnx for reply..Actually I can do either Tomcat or Apache..No issues...but I just wanted to know if things will be easier with jsp. Cause in future I have to enhance my php code to do other handling on server side...

Comment: No problem. I know isn't much of the help but it is something to think about. I never done JSP myself, but I know java and PHP just fine. Do you feel comfortable programming in PHP or Java? PHP has already many available framework such as Zend, cakephp or symphony, I am sure jsp has their own frameworks too.

Comment: I agree with joze. It comes down to experience and personal preferences if nothing has been determined by someone else (e.g. company policies). I personally thinks Java offers plenty frameworks to nicely deal with server side stuff. If you have no need for a web UI, JSPs are not the way to go forward with. Choose a REST-framework instead (I assume REST-frameworks are available for PHP as well). For Java Lars Vogel has written a nice [REST tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).